# Spot the error in this program that generates a “random walk"

Tags: c, arrays

Write a program that generates a “random walk" across a 10 x 10 array. The array will contain characters (all '.' initially). The program must randomly “walk” from element to element, always going up, down, left, or right by one element. The elements visited by the program will be labeled with the letters A through Z, in the order visited. Here's an example of the desired output:
[image]

This is my beautiful code that sometimes works horrible, and sometimes doesn't work at all:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 10//max 127 because of signed char array
#define DIRECTIONS 4//up, down, left, right

int main(void)
{
    bool success0 = true, success1 = true, success2 = true, success3 = true;//to check if one path is available or not
    int row, column, direction;
    signed char array[SIZE][SIZE], letter;

    //seeds the random number generator
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    //INITIALIZES ARRAY
    for(row = 0; row < SIZE; row++){
        for(column = 0; column < SIZE; column++){
            array[row][column] = '.';
        }
    }


    //PATH OF THE ALPHABET
    row = 0;
    column = 0;
    for(letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++){
        direction = rand() % DIRECTIONS;
        //Outer if checks that we are not in the boundary of the array, outer else applies the offset.
        //Inner if checks that the element is "empty", inner else makes the letter loop to be repeated.
        switch(direction){
            case 0://up
            if(row == 0){
                letter--;
                success0 = false;
            }
            else{
                row--;
                if(array[row][column] == '.'){
                    array[row][column] = letter;
                    success0 = true;
                    success1 = true;
                    success2 = true;
                    success3 = true;
                }
                else{
                    letter--;
                    success0 = false;
                }
            }
            break;

            case 1://right
            if(column == SIZE - 1){
                letter--;
                success1 = false;
            }
            else{
                column++;
                if(array[row][column] == '.'){
                    array[row][column] = letter;
                    success0 = true;
                    success1 = true;
                    success2 = true;
                    success3 = true;
                }
                else{
                    letter--;
                    success1 = false;
                }
            }
            break;

            case 2://down
            if(row == SIZE - 1){
                letter--;
                success2 = false;
            }
            else{
                row++;
                if(array[row][column] == '.'){
                    array[row][column] = letter;
                    success0 = true;
                    success1 = true;
                    success2 = true;
                    success3 = true;
                }
                else{
                    letter--;
                    success2 = false;
                }
            }
            break;

            case 3://left
            if(column == 0){
                letter--;
                success3 = false;
            }
            else{
                column--;
                if(array[row][column] == '.'){
                    array[row][column] = letter;
                    success0 = true;
                    success1 = true;
                    success2 = true;
                    success3 = true;
                }
                else{
                    letter--;
                    success3 = false;
                }
            }
            break;

            default: printf("Error"); break;
        }
        //checks if all 4 directions are blocked
        if(success0 == false && success1 == false && success2 == false && success3 == false){
            printf("All four directions are blocked: program must terminate.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //PRINTS ARRAY
    for(row = 0; row < SIZE; row++){
        for(column = 0; column < SIZE; column++){
            putchar(array[row][column]);
            putchar(' ');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hint: Use the srand and rand functions to generate random numbers. Before performing a move, check that (a) it won’t go outside the array, and (b) it doesn’t take us to an element that already has a letter assigned. If either condition is violated, try moving in another direction. If all four directions are blocked, the program must terminate.

Comment: You want us to do your homework or?

Comment: This doesn't feel like a question. It's more of a challenge being imposed on other users. Also, describing your code as beautiful but also saying that it sometimes works horrible is kind of confusing.

Comment: Spot the error? How about tell us what the compiler shows as being the error? If it compiles then that's your error and there are simple debugging techniques that could easily find said error.

Comment: Well I did "my homework" but as I don't have a teacher and I tried for hours without success, after checking in the web (there are other ways to solve the same problem), I am stucked. Is it so hard to help? I am not demanding, if you dont want to help me it is ok. But I have to try all alternatives before giving up.

Comment: Okay, but you have to explain what doesn't work or what the problem is? We need a problem statement and not a guessing game.

Comment: I tried to debugg with my complier CodeBlocks but the debugger gets stucked in the initalization of the array (which is fine by the way) so I cant go any further than that with the debugger. The program works buggy sometimes and other times it just goes with the "All four directions are blocked: program must terminate."

Comment: I haven't used CodeBlocks but you should be able to set a breakpoint somewhere else in the code so that it will run until it reaches that point. Also, you could use print statements to 'see' what is happening while the code is running. For instance print out each direction it takes, get out a piece of paper with a 10x10 grid and follow it. You might just discover something.

Comment: Thanks BinaryJudy, I tried again with the debugger and I realized that I had to go through all the 100 clicks to initialize the array. Then it was easy to spot the error. I don't know how to automatically do the initialization loop without getting into it. Breakpoints didnt work out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74160/discussion-between-user3646717-and-binaryjudy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spotted the main problem.  When you walk into an existing letter, you forgot to back up before you try again:

```
        case 0://up
        if(row == 0){
            letter--;
            success0 = false;
        }
        else{
            row--;
            if(array[row][column] == '.'){
                array[row][column] = letter;
                success0 = true;
                success1 = true;
                success2 = true;
                success3 = true;
            }
            else{
                row++; // THIS WAS MISSING
                letter--;
                success0 = false;
            }
        }
        break;
```

You need to fix up each direction like the above.

By the way, it seems normal to get the "all directions blocked" message, because you consider the path already walked to be impassable. So you could easily walk your way into a dead end. For example, if in your picture, if from `H` you went upwards to `I`, you would be at a dead end. Instead of `return 0` at that point, you should `break` to print the array.

Comment: Yes! I totally forgot to back up the occupied row/column; I followed your recommendation of breaking instead of returning. You are a fast genius, how did you spot the problem?